# can't install next.js using bunx ! by bunx create-next-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, bun

[screenshoot of command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9BN8.png)it's says " The application path is not writable, please check folder permissions and try again.
It is likely you do not have write permissions for this folder. "
how can i solve it ?

create next.js app by bun
by :

```
bunx create-next-app
```

Comment: You need to execute `chmod 700 bun-next.js`. Try this one and let me know it works or not

Comment: something didn't work i'm getting permissions error

Comment: try with `sudo bunx create-next-app`. it will prompt for a password

Comment: same problem nothing changed

Comment: try chmod 777 at the folder which are you trying to create `chmod 777 $(pwd)`